# after_create callback and external model - what's a good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models `Board` and `Category`(tree structure using ancestry gem) with has_many/belongs_to relationship.

When I create new Board instance I automatically want to create root Category for it. I do it with Board after_save callback.

```
after_create do 
  categories.create(name: "Main Category", description: nil)
end
```

In my other question I got suggestion:

> It's not good practice to use callbacks on external models/classes.
>   Category is outside of Board, so Board should not call Category in
>   it's callbacks which is supposed a private space. Instead, a better
>   approach is to add root category to a board in BoardsController's
>   #create

But on the other hand, I heard about fat model/skin controller principle. 
So what's the good practice with logic like in this case?

Comment: I think it may violate skinny-controllers approach if you create it in controller. On the other hand creating a `Category` as a callback in `Board` model class may become a drawback later wneh you would wish to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers).

`Observer classes respond to life cycle callbacks to implement trigger-like behavior outside the original class. This is a great way to reduce the clutter that normally comes when the model class is burdened with functionality that doesn't pertain to the core responsibility of the class`